# Is it possible to create a user account that cannot modify **any** file on the computer?

Tags: windows-7, security, user-accounts, guest-account

The question is quite self explanatory but just to add a few details.

The user cannot modify (can read, but can't write/delete) **any** files on the computer, which includes:

- Desktop shortcuts
- Files on another drive
- Files (Obviously) on other user accounts
- Windows system files

Comment: The guest account, although not as restricted as you're asking, was set up purely for this purpose...

Comment: A "Kiosk mode" sounds similar to what you want, where settings are basically "read-only" and changing things isn't allowed. Some Linux desktops support it, not sure about Win... Or run a Linux live, you can change files temporarily while running, but the entire filesystem is read-only and all changes are lost on reboot.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. You might want to use virtual machines in order to be able to reset to a previous state. Typically VMware or VirtualBox are used for this purpose.